# Difference between Barracuda and Antelope INNODB format

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

What are differences between INNODB file formats Barracuda and Antelope, except that Barracuda supports table compression? Barracuda format is newer, but in MySQL >= 5.5.7 the default file format is Antelope (according to [MySQL website innodb_file_format option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format))

Is there any speed difference or recommendation which format is better and why is now default format Antelope which is older?

Comment: Note that Barracuda *was* the default but was reversed for reasons of backwards compatibility.  References: [1](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/14/innodb-file-formats-here-is-one-pitfall-to-avoid/) [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antelope is older.

Barracuda allows you to go beyond 767 bytes for an index column.

I have not heard of any reason to switch wholesale.